# Автоматическое написание кода, как на сайте http://thecodeplayer.com

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте!

Как реализована фишка «автоматического написания кода» в уроках на сайте http://thecodeplayer.com?

Answer (score 3):

Можно посмотреть исходный код, он же не обфусцирован. Конкретнее, в файле [walkthroughv3.js](http://thecodeplayer.com/js/walkthroughv3.js) функция `set_slide_content` вызывается для каждого слайда. В [другом файле](http://thecodeplayer.com/jsdata/js_data/8283/) (для проекта [javascript clock](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/javascript-color-clock)) хранятся данные для слайдов, а именно добавленные символы, удаленные символы, начальные и конечные позиции курсора (?), тип редактора. Можно использовать отладчик Developer Tools в Chrome, поставив breakpoint на функцию, и уточнить детали.

Comment: т.е. для каждого урока они создают массив символов кода? Или этот процесс как-то можно автоматизировать?

Comment: или они парсят готовый код и складывают его в массив?

Comment: @vinnie я так думаю, что кто-то сначала набирает этот код, программа фиксируют действия и формирует массив. Это можно предположить по опечаткам, которые затем исправляются.

Comment: неужели нельзя проще сделать

Comment: @vinnie думаю, что нет. Код же набирается не просто от начала до конца, а по определённой логике, которую едва ли возможно запрограммировать.

Comment: Сделал свою топорную реалиацию)) 
http://jsfiddle.net/3msq50tc/2/